# Displaying data from JSON in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here, but I can't render the JSON data to the page, only able to out put the JSON formatted data, and not just specific keys (e.g., Name: Abbey Malt).

This is my controller:

```
app.controller('beerController', function($scope, $http, $modal) {
$http.get("http://api.brewerydb.com/v2/fermentables", {
    params: {
      key: 'xxx'
    }
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    $scope.response = response.data.name;
    console.log(response);
  });
};
```

And the HTML:

```
    <div ng-controller="beerController">
    <div class="container">
      <h3>Latest Releases ({{currentPage}} pages)</h3>
      <div class="row">
        <div ng-repeat="items in response">
          <li>{{data.name}}</li>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Lastly, here's a screenshot of the console and how the JSON object is structured:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your code to

```
app.controller('beerController', function($scope, $http, $modal) {
    $http.get("http://api.brewerydb.com/v2/fermentables", {
        params: {
          key: 'xxx'
        }
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        $scope.response = response.data.data;
        console.log(response);
      });
    };
```

and view

```
<div>
    <div ng-controller="beerController">
    <div class="container">
      <h3>Latest Releases ({{currentPage}} pages)</h3>
      <div class="row">
        <div ng-repeat="item in response">
          <li>{{item.name}}</li>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was so close! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

put that on your controller:

```
$scope.items = response.data.data;
```

and html would be like this

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <li>{{item.name}}</li>
</div>
```

Comment: @user3438917 is it clear to you why this is the correct answer? It looks like the API returns an object `data` that is an array. Angular itself will deserialize the JSON as `resonse.data`. So it becomes `response.data.data`. Then you are iterating over the items you have exposed in your controller. You are referencing each item as `item`. You can then access the `name` as `item.name`.